# Setting the start dir when calling Powershell from .NET?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using the System.Management.Automation API to call PowerShell scripts a C# WPF app. In the following example, how would you change the start directory ($PWD) so it executes foo.ps1 from C:\scripts\ instead of the location of the .exe it was called from?

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        pipeline.Commands.Add(@"C:\scripts\foo.ps1");
        pipeline.Invoke();
    }
    runspace.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to change the `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` to change the working path for your PowerShell scripts. It can be quite dangerous to do this because this may have unintentional side effects if you're running other code that is sensitive to your current directory.

Since you're providing a `Runspace`, all you need to do is set the `Path` properties on the `SessionStateProxy`:

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    runspace.SessionStateProxy.Path.SetLocation(directory);
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        pipeline.Commands.Add(@"C:\scripts\foo.ps1");
        pipeline.Invoke();
    }
    runspace.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution for remote calls? RemoteSessionStateProxy.Path throws a PSNotSupportedException.

Comment: @Rookian: Running the `Set-Location` cmdlet may be your only choice in that scenario.

Answer (score 8):

Setting `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` ahead of time will do what you want.

Rather than adding `Set-Location` to your scrip, you should set `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` *any time **before** opening* the Runspace. It will inherit whatever the CurrentDirectory is when it's opened:

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\scripts";
    runspace.Open();
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        pipeline.Commands.Add(@".\foo.ps1");
        pipeline.Invoke();
    }
    runspace.Close();
}
```

And remember, `Set-Location` doesn't set the .net framework's `CurrentDirectory` so if you're calling .Net methods which work on the "current" location, you need to set it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Anything wrong with doing:

```
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(@"set-location c:\scripts;.\foo.ps1")
```

?

-Oisin

Answer (score 1):

You can set the working directory in powershell with the following command

```
set-location c:\mydirectory
```

You can also try your PowerShell startup script ($profile).
C:....\MyDocs\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
But only if this directory is fixed and does not change

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the application handle it, you can include this at the start of your script,

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
```

It would execute the rest of the script in its installation directory.

But beware, the PowerShell 'current location' is NOT the same as the working directory of your application, they're just initialized the same when you launch powershell.

Set-Location may play tricks on you if you launch executables that depend on the current directory, or if your script contains framework API calls like this example:

```
PS C:\Users\luc> Set-Location C:\
PS C:\> [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
C:\Users\luc
```

That being said, I would often prefer Mike Bailey's answer. I just wanted to give a solution that has its merits if the script isn't always installed in the same directory (different path on a development machine than in production, as is usually the case).